# Android In-app Billing - Item Price (Issue)

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing, skus

I need to get sku price. 10 skus placed in dev. console.
Using this code I can get only information about purchased items.

```
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
            mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, querySkus);
    ...
    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
            .getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);

    // ONLY 2 PURCHASED ITEMS HERE!!!
    logDebug("Skus count: " + responseList.size());
    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
        SkuDetails d = new SkuDetails(itemType, thisResponse);
        logDebug("Got sku details: " + d);
        inv.addSkuDetails(d);
    }
```

So, **how to get the price for non-purchased skus**?

Answer (score 0):

Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);

The skuList should contain all the SKUs that you want the information about.

Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
            mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, querySkus);
make sure that the itemType is the one that you have selected while listing product on developer console.

For example if there are 6 items with type "inapp" and 4 items with type "subs" then if you want the details of those 6 items with type "inapp" then make sure that the above itemType variable contains the value "inapp".

Comment: I have only inapp types, and I placed all skus in bundle. Problem still not resolved.